# Change product prices via a hook in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

IN WooCommerce, I need to multiply all product prices by a number. So I have used the following *(via a plugin)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price', array( $this, 'my_custom_price'), 99);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', array( $this, 'my_custom_price'), 99);

function my_custom_price( $original_price ) {
  global $post, $woocommerce;

  //Logic for calculating the new price here
  $new_price = $original_price * 2;

  //Return the new price (this is the price that will be used everywhere in the store)
  return $new_price;
 }
```

But, that **doesn't work for variation products.** I have tried the following hooks with no luck:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_variation_regular_price', array( $this, 'my_custom_price'), 99);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_variation_price', array( $this, 'my_custom_price'), 99);
```

The only one that works half way is this one:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', array( $this, 'my_custom_price'), 99);
```

But that just changed the overall price, not the selected variation price. See the image below, price is BsF. 200 and the overall price is right, 200 x 2 =  400, but the variation price when selected still shows 200:

**Note: I need it to actually change, so display html hooks wont work.**

[image: Variation Price]

Is there anything I'm missing, or something wrong?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> **Update** *(December 2020)*
>
> - 2 code versions for themes and plugins *(works in Woocommerce 3.3.x too)*
> - Cached variations prices in Woocommerce 3 *(Update and addition)*: 
>   Now using `woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash` filter hook much more efficient, instead of `wc_delete_product_transients()`… See [this related thread](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/caching-and-dynamic-pricing-upcoming-changes-to-the-get_variation_prices-method/)
> - Added product price filter widget hooks *(see at the end)*.

**1) Plugin version** with a constructor function:

The hooks that you are using are deprecated in WooCommerce 3+

To make it work for all products prices, **including variations prices**, you should use this:

```
## The following goes inside the constructor ##

// Simple, grouped and external products
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', array( $this, 'custom_price' ), 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', array( $this, 'custom_price' ), 99, 2 );
// Variations 
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', array( $this, 'custom_price' ), 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', array( $this, 'custom_price' ), 99, 2 );

// Variable (price range)
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', array( $this, 'custom_variable_price' ), 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', array( $this, 'custom_variable_price' ), 99, 3 );

// Handling price caching (see explanations at the end)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash', array( $this, 'add_price_multiplier_to_variation_prices_hash' ), 99, 3 );


## This goes outside the constructor ##

// Utility function to change the prices with a multiplier (number)
public function get_price_multiplier() {
    return 2; // x2 for testing
}

public function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    return (float) $price * get_price_multiplier();
}

public function custom_variable_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    return (float) $price * get_price_multiplier();
}

public function add_price_multiplier_to_variation_prices_hash( $price_hash, $product, $for_display ) {
    $price_hash[] = get_price_multiplier();
    return $price_hash;
}
```

The code tested and perfectly works (only) in WooCommerce 3+.

---

**2) For theme version:** **`functions.php`** file on active child theme (or active theme):

```
// Utility function to change the prices with a multiplier (number)
function get_price_multiplier() {
    return 2; // x2 for testing
}

// Simple, grouped and external products
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
// Variations
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    return (float) $price * get_price_multiplier();
}

// Variable (price range)
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variable_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'custom_variable_price', 99, 3 );
function custom_variable_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    // Delete product cached price  (if needed)
    // wc_delete_product_transients($variation->get_id());

    return (float) $price * get_price_multiplier();
}

// Handling price caching (see explanations at the end)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash', 'add_price_multiplier_to_variation_prices_hash', 99, 3 );
function add_price_multiplier_to_variation_prices_hash( $price_hash, $product, $for_display ) {
    $price_hash[] = get_price_multiplier();
    return $price_hash;
}
```

Tested and works on woocommerce 3+

---

For products in sale you have those hooks:

- `woocommerce_product_get_sale_price` *(Simple, grouped and external products)*
- `woocommerce_variation_prices_sale_price` *(Variable products (min-max))*
- `woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price` *(Products variations)*

---

#### Cached prices and woocommerce 3:

The 3 filters hooks involved in variations cached prices are:

- `woocommerce_variation_prices_price`
- `woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price`
- `woocommerce_variation_prices_sale_price`

> Introduced in Woocommerce 3, `woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash` filter hook will **allow to refresh variations cached prices in a much more efficient way**, without deleting related transients anytime that this hooks are executed.

So performances will stay boosted *(Thanks to [Matthew Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547970/matthew-clark) that pointed this better way)*

See: [Caching and dynamic pricing – upcoming changes to the get_variation_prices method](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/caching-and-dynamic-pricing-upcoming-changes-to-the-get_variation_prices-method/)

---

**For filtering product prices with a widget** *(min and max price)*, use the following hooks:

- `woocommerce_price_filter_widget_min_amount` *that has one argument* `$price`
- `woocommerce_price_filter_widget_max_amount` *that has one argument* `$price`

Comment: Thank you! Now it works only if I delete DB transients with a plugin to see the changes. Is there any way to delete those transients automatically with a function??

Comment: Can you please guide me how to add it properly to my_custom_price function? Thanks in advance, great answear!

Comment: @KronosL Updated my answer with `wc_delete_product_transients($post->ID);` … as this seems specific when used from a plugin. When you use that hooks through the theme, this problem doesn't exist. After this will not be enough… so you will have to search a bit.

Comment: that doesnt seem to work all prices are turning into 0

Comment: @kos I have tested, corrected and updated the code... There is 2 versions now, so choose the good one depending if it's for a plugin or the active theme function.php file.

Comment: Actually, instead of calling `wc_delete_product_transients()` (which is defeating the performance boost the transient was designed to employ), you can simply hook into the [woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) filter to cause different transients to be saved and reused.

See [this blog post](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/caching-and-dynamic-pricing-upcoming-changes-to-the-get_variation_prices-method/) on the official WooCommerce development blog.

Comment: @MatthewClark I have updated my answer code and explanations related to `woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash` filter hook usage instead of using inefficient `wc_delete_product_transients()`. Thanks.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec my edit was correct, no? You've put woocommerce_variation_prices_sale_price twice

Comment: @Leonid Sorry but my answer here is related to the OP question (provided code and details) **that has nothing to do product prices in widgets**… So I didn't forget anything. The hooks that I use in my answer are directly related to `WC_Product` price getter methods.

Comment: Yes, but then when using your code, the standard WooCommerce filtering widget will not work correctly.