# Change programmatically products prices for a product category globally in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, price

Is it possible to change price for all products in a specific product category in Woocommerce?

for example if I want to change all products prices in 'shirts' product category to 50, is it possible?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what does your research says

Answer (score 3):

To change the product prices with a fixed amount of `50` **for an entire product category** `shirts`:

```
// Simple, grouped and external products
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'conditional_custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'conditional_custom_price', 99, 2 );
// Variable
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'conditional_custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'conditional_custom_price', 99, 2 );
function conditional_custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    if( has_term( 'shirts', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        // Delete product cached price  (if needed uncomment it)
        // wc_delete_product_transients($product->get_id());

        $price = 50; // X2 for testing
    }
    return $price;
}

// Variations
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'conditional_custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'conditional_custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );
function conditional_custom_variation_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    if( has_term( 'shirts', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        // Delete product cached price  (if needed uncomment below)
        // wc_delete_product_transients($variation->get_id());

        $price = 50;
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Based on this answer: [Change product prices via a hook in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806249/change-product-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3/45807054#45807054)

It handle all kind of Woocommerce product types. The conditional Wordpress function `has_term()` can handle a **term Id**, a **term slug** or a **term name** regarding any product category.

Comment: Its Just for display purpose, We can also add code to modify values in DB

Comment: I was suggesting, We can also add Code to update code in DB too :-)

Comment: @SudharshanNair Yes but it is not what the OP asked. Updating products in DB  has already been answered a lot in StackOverFlow. Thanks for suggesting :)