# Woocommerce change product unit price by multiplying quantity variation?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-quantity

First of all, i'am newbie at server side coding like php, mysql etc.

So that i want to make things easier to explain my issue as short as possible :

I have website that has all **"variable products of woocommerce"**

I have attributes for variations like :

Color : red,yellow,green,...
Dimensions : 10x10,10x22,15x27,...
**Quantity :** 50,100,150,200,...1000(max)

As you see variations i want to update its price like :

[red][10x10][any quantity] = **12$ + VAT** --> this is unit

If user selects **50** price should be **600$ + VAT** --> this is total

To briefly, i want to show unit prices at home page on woocommerce shop widget.After user enters product detail page if he/she choose quantity the final price should be changed than is sent to cart.

I've found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806249/change-product-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3/45807054#45807054) very close to my question but because of i don't know much about php coding, i did not understand it clearly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am choosing product to single selling so that the woocommerce quantity field is disabled. Some of variations of products can not let quantity become 50 it starts with 100 if you choose some options, so that i can not use woocommerce general 50 step quantity adjustment. However, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I don't understand exactly. I have custom variations for each product. How can i use quantity field as multiplier on a function ? Can you provide some examples please

Comment: It is not complicated as you imply. I assign quantities to items. Just want to multiply these numbers to its prices. It is simple i think. I only do not have any information about how to write hook on functions.php etc.

Comment: Any possible solution would be appreciated

Comment: Why the other comments were being deleted ?