# Regenerate transients for defined $product or $variation Objects in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I really wonder if there is a way to regenerate all the native transients for a given product or variation object.

I'm in a case where I display dynamic prices, and everything is fine. But I need to update transients like `wc_prices_{id}` in order for it to take into account this new custom price. If not, the first page load is horrible (especially on the shop page displaying several products at a time).

I'm hooking into `woocommerce_product_variation_get_price`, `woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price`, `woocommerce_variation_prices_price` and `woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price` (in short, this modify on the fly **EVERY SINGLE PRICE** of a page, and if it's a parent containing children, it change prices for children too in order to calculate the range prices (min/max) of the parent).

When digging into Woocommerce code, I have found which method generate the prices transient : it's `read_price_data()` located in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-variable-data-store-cpt.php`. But I can't find a way to call it my Cron Job script to call it on a product or variation object.

Are you guys aware of solution for this task?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

The 3 filters hooks involved in variations cached prices are:

- `woocommerce_variation_prices_price`
- `woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price`
- `woocommerce_variation_prices_sale_price`

To regenerate cached prices, you could use on those hooks:

```
wc_delete_product_transients( $variation->get_id() );
```

But it will slow down your web site performances.

> Introduced since Woocommerce 3, `woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash` filter hook will allow to refresh variations cached prices in a much more efficient way, without deleting related transients anytime that those hooks are triggered.

#### Documentation and related thread:

- [**Caching and dynamic pricing – upcoming changes to the get_variation_prices method**](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/caching-and-dynamic-pricing-upcoming-changes-to-the-get_variation_prices-method/)
- [Change product prices via a hook in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806249/change-product-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3/45807054#45807054)
- [All related threads using `woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash` filter hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash)