# WooCommerce: Get product variation custom field value in a hooked function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, product-variations

This is how, I add an admin custom field for product Variations:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'add_custom_field_to_variations', 10, 3 );
     
function add_custom_field_to_variations( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => 'custom_field[' . $loop . ']',
        'class' => 'short',
        'label' => __( 'Custom Field', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'custom_field', true )
    ) );
}
```

Save custom field on product variation save:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_custom_field_variations', 10, 2 );
function save_custom_field_variations( $variation_id, $i ) {
    $custom_field = $_POST['custom_field'][$i];
    if ( isset( $custom_field ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'custom_field', esc_attr( $custom_field ) );
}
```

Store custom field value into variation data

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'add_custom_field_variation_data' );
function add_custom_field_variation_data( $variations ) {
    $variations ['custom_field'] = '<div class="woocommerce_custom_field">Custom Field: <span>' . get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'custom_field', true ) . '</span></div>';
    return $variations;
}
```

The value is saving and displaying in the single product page but the below function is not returning the value

Trying to retrieve Value of the custom field in a function:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'get_custom_variable_price' )
function get_custom_variable_price() {

    global $post;
    $custom_value = get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'custom_field', true );
    $custom_value = (float)$custom_value;
    return $custom_value;   
}
```

I need to get just the value *(which is float number)*:

Comment: Where do you use your last function?… please add some more context as your question is actually unclear…

Comment: I am using last function on 'woocommerce_variation_prices_price'. The purpose is to get the custom value to be multiplied by the variation product price

Comment: I have edited your question then, and answered. Some feed back on the answer below will be appreciated please.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes and missing things in your las function *(see below)*.

Now there are 2 ways to get the custom field value in that hooked function:

1). Using `WC_Data` `get_meta()` method *(since WooCommerce 3)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variable_price', 100, 3 );
function custom_variable_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    $value = floatval( $variation->get_meta( 'custom_field' ) );
    if( $value > 0 ) {
        $price = $value; 
    }
    return $price;
}
```

2). Or using WordPress `get_post_meta()` function *(the old way)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variable_price', 100, 3 );
function custom_variable_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    $value = floatval( floatval( get_post_meta( $variation->get_id(), 'custom_field', true ) );
    if( $value > 0  ) {
        $price = $value; 
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested, works for both.

> **Important note:** You may not see the result in front end, as variable product price range is cached in WooCommerce to improve performances *(see the linked thread below for better understanding)*.

Related thread: [Change product prices via a hook in WooCommerce 3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806249/change-product-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3/45807054#45807054)

---

**Addition related to your others functions**

Since WooCommerce 3 you could update your 2nd and 3rd function as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'save_custom_field_variation_value', 10, 2 );
function save_custom_field_variation_value( $variation, $i ) {
    if( isset($_POST['custom_field'][$i]) ) {
        $variation->update_meta_data( 'custom_field', floatval( sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_field'][$i]) ) );
    }
}
```

and 3rd function

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'add_variation_custom_field_value_to_variation_data', 10, 3 );
function add_variation_custom_field_value_to_variation_data( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    if ( $value = $variation->get_meta( 'custom_field' ) ) {
        $variation_data['custom_field'] = '<div class="woocommerce_custom_field">' .__("Custom Field") . ': <span>' . $value . '</span></div>';
    }
    return $variation_data;
}
```

Comment: Hi @loicTheAztec
Thanks for ans & efforts. I try both version but its not working and showing a critical error on front-end.
I think I didn't asked rightly, Let me try explain again;
check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806249/change-product-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3/45807054#45807054

you have answered this also, what I needed is to get the custom added variation field value to be multiplied.
2) For theme version:
``function get_price_multiplier() {
    return 2; // x2 for testing 
// I NEED TO LOAD CUSTOM FIELD VALUE HERE}``

Comment: Actually it is not retrieving the custom_field ID nor get_meta is working and also I tried with get_the_ID() but they all are returning null

Comment: I have explained the requirement here;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66735034/woocommerce-product-variation-custom-field-and-its-price-calculation