# WooCommerce Product Variation Custom Field and Its Price Calculation

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

There

I wanted to add a custom field in WooCommerce->Product->variation Tab so that a store manager can input the quantity for that particular variation.

For example;
Product: Mango (Different Types) - Every type has different price break down
Variation 1: Bag of Mangoes
Variation 2: Basket of Mangoes
Variation 3: Box of Mangoes

Now, the case is; Store manager **don't** want to show the amount by weight (1kg, 5kg, 10kg) All he want is to let the buyer choose from these three options (Bag, Basket and Box). On the variation single page the store manager want to show the custom cheap cost of one single Mango and Upon selection of any variation the price comes at Add to cart should display like this;

"$6.14 / Bag" OR "$26.21 / Basket" OR "$41.4 / Box"

The price should calculated as per the selection(s). Below is how he needed;

ON CMS;
Regular Price: $1.2 | Sale Price: $0.99
CUSTOM FIELD UNIT: "Bag"
CUSTOM FIELD VALUE: 6.21

ON Front-end;
As selection of Type of Mangoes and Bag, Basket, Box. The Price below should come like this;

> Working while triggers => [0.99 X 6.21] (after round off) = $6.14  (This is what is needed)

$6.14 / Bag
And so on..