# Enable/Disable Sale Price Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a way to programmatically enable/disable Sale Price of each product variation in woocommerce?

So i have Custom Meta Data, which is multiple Date Range, if the current date is not within those multiple date range. I want to disable the Sale Price.

I tried using ChatGPT but all the code he gave me does not work :D

Thanks

Comment: For dynamic product prices, the correct hooks to be used are like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45807054/3730754

Comment: Thanks, ill try it hopefully will work.