# Change product price based on customer billing country in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I need to change the currency depending on the billing country, with the following code it is possible in a certain way, but it only works with simple products, not with variable ones.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', $product, 2);

function return_custom_price($price, $product) {    
    global $post, $woocommerce;
    
    // Array containing country codes
    $county = array('US');
    // Amount to increase by
    //$amount = 5;
    // If the custromers shipping country is in the array
    if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_billing_country(), $county ) && is_checkout() ){
        // Return the price plus the $amount
       return $new_price = ($price/260)*1.25;
    } else {
         
        // Otherwise just return the normal price
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hook `woocommerce_get_price` is obsolete and deprecated since WooCommerce 3 and has been replaced with the following hooks:

- `woocommerce_product_get_price` (for products)
- `woocommerce_product_variation_get_price` (for variations of a variable product).

There are some other mistakes in your code. Try the following revised code:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'country_based_cart_item_price', 100, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'country_based_cart_item_price', 100, 2);

function country_based_cart_item_price( $price, $product ) {    
    // Define below in the array the desired country codes
    $targeted_countries = array('US');
    $billing_country    = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();

    // Only on cart and checkout pages 
    if ( ( is_checkout() || is_cart() ) && in_array($billing_country, $targeted_countries) ){
        // Returns changed price
       return $price / 260 * 1.25;
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

See: [Change product prices via a hook in WooCommerce 3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806249/change-product-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3/45807054#45807054)